# How JAXB annotations behaves in axis2 runtime?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, apache-axis, websphere-liberty

I am developing soap web service with bottom-up approach.
Using **Liberty 18.0.0.2 , Java 8, Apache Axis2 Runtime** (to generate java2wsdl), **Maven** and **Spring Tool Suite**.

Process: Having the class with *@WebService* and *@Webmethod*. Generated the services.xml with axis2 runtime. Getting the wsdl by http://localhost:9081/MyServices/Services/SampleService?wsdl

I successfully developed the webservice and able to get the response in **SOAPUI**. But i want to change the format of the response. That's why i included the Jaxb Annotations like *@XmlElement @XmlRootElement
@XmlAttribute* in my Pojo. None of the annotation is reflected in my response(i.e., Generated WSDL file itself not containing the JAXB annotated Element and Attribute). Am i missing anything here? Kindly help me out on this?

Comment: Are you planning on using the jaxws-2.2 feature that's provided by Liberty to deploy your built application? If that's the case, I'd think that you'd want to use Liberty's wsgen tool (rather than java2wsdl) to ensure you're generating a WSDL and related artfacts intended for deployment on Liberty.

Comment: Created wsdl using Liberty's wsgen. That WSDL file having jaxb annotated elements. Since i am using AxisServlet in web.xml getting the same response even though in Liberty wsgen generated wsdl. Any other suggestions?